# What does a hybrid Bayesian network contain?

Tags: bayesian-networks, probabilistic-graphical-models, probabilistic-machine-learning

The field of artificial intelligence is so vast. There are many methodologies for handling continuous data, and I have just read about the *hybrid Bayesian network*. I just want to know that what a hybrid Bayesian network contains?

Comment: Have a look at http://people.cs.aau.dk/~tdn/papers/langseth-etal-09.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bayesian network where the random variables represented can be continuous or discrete. Usually the continuous variables are handled with Normal distribution with an input of some linear combination of the variables it is dependent on.

Much more detail can be found in Koller's Probabilistic Graphical Model book: http://pgm.stanford.edu/